# How to pop and melt an nested array in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Here's my dataset

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 ifa|                 gps|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|000004bf-6332-447...|[[qqy815ggy, 7, 2...|
|000016f7-a7ce-43a...|[[qr6x03d2n, 6, 2...|
|00004391-3d58-485...|[[qw8nv82ph, 4, 2...|
|00004a35-f154-4da...|[[qxg0fyr86, 3, 2...|
|00005076-ea28-455...|[[qw8nv82ph, 3, 2...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

What I normally do in pandas is

`df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('gps').values.tolist(),index=df.index)).melt('ifa')`

If you know, do you know [pop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

What I did in pyspark

`df2 = df.withColumn(df.gps.values.tolist(), explode("df.gps"))`

The error message is

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Expexcted output (also output on pandas)

```
    ifa             variable   0         1      2          3          ...
0   0001d713-7f41   0          qq5ggy    11.0   2021-08-01 07:29:24   ...
```

Comment: Please add the expected output in your question. I assume not everyone will know what `pop` and `melt` are supposed to do.

Comment: @philantrovert done

Comment: Could you design a **minimal reproducible** example?  Here, it is quite hard to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: is it `df.withColumn('gps', explode('gps')).select('ifa', 'gps.*')`?  I am wildly guessing from the data (`[[` and the things in list)